# Responsive table with image on left and Text on right

Tags: html, css

I want to create a html page (blog post style) with Responsive table with images on left and Text on right . I want a blue background. and text will have links to the post page. I want to have the css inside the html head.

Any ideas how I can achieve it?

I wanna create something like this

http://www.bucaillelegacy.com/light/blog.html

Comment: what have you already tried

Comment: Where is your codepen or something?

Comment: <div class="page-slideshow narrow">
    <div class="hero di-hero">
        <div>
    <a href="" title="Delicious Ideas from AllRecipes.com">
        <div class="slide-content">
            <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/fdec4733b4814d9e958b7f86c25020b5.jpg" width="152" height="150" alt="Delicious Ideas from AllRecipes.com" >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place the image at the beginning of the text, align it to the left and the text after it will wrap around the image, give it a slight margin-right to increase the space between image and text, resulting in:

```
<img src="image.png" align="left" style="margin-right:10px;">Text here.
```